# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thisArg')

Tags: vite

I built a Vite app with React JS and I am trying to deploy it to Firebase. The dev mode works just find, but when I ran the command line "npm run build", I get the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thisArg')
error during build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thisArg')
    at CallExpression.applyDeoptimizations (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:9537:30)
    at CallExpression.hasEffects (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:9503:22)
    at ExpressionStatement.hasEffects (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:5750:28)
    at Program.hasEffects (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:11487:22)
    at Program.hasCachedEffects (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:11482:44)
    at Module.hasEffects (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13379:75)
    at addSideEffectDependencies (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13719:72)
    at Module.addRelevantSideEffectDependencies (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13726:9)
    at Module.getDependenciesToBeIncluded (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13237:18)
    at addStaticDependencies (file:///D:/NodeJS%20projects/BlogApiSite/BlogClientSite/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14947:33)
```

I tried the solution of deleting the node modules folder and running 'npm install', but it didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the issue. The issue was that there was a bug in Rollup. What I had to do is update Rollup to its latest version.